# Cannot include jQuery and Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, node.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, bower

I installed jQuery and Bootstrap with Bower.

I got this error

```
syntaxerror: expected expression, got '<' <!doctype html> jquery
```

My code

```
<script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

There is my folder structure

```
http://laravel.io/bin/d9MnD
```

I also tried to put the code in head, but did not work

Here is my server data

```
var express = require('express'),
        app = express();

app
    .use(express.static('./public'))
    .get('*', function (req, res) {
        res.sendfile('public/main.html');
    })
    .listen(3000);
```

Comment: for starters the order is wrong. Also seems like path to jQuery is wrong and server is returning html

Comment: seems to be fine though, have you tried by including `jquery` first then, `bootstrap`?

Comment: Can you please explain more? @charlietfl

Comment: I fixed it. It is 2 a.m. now. Still getting the same error @narainsagar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this on server.js:

```
app.use('/bower_components',  express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));
```

now in anything place I can use this and work fine, example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

with this you call directly to the folder